# Как подключить View из другого файла на ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Есть разметка и в определённых местах я хочу добавить View из других файлов.
Как такое реализовать с помощью хелпера, что б,например пишешь "Вставить содержимое" и даёшь путь к файлу(и что б вложенный файл обрабатывался Razor и в нём можно было ещё что-то обработать)?

Comment: `Html.RenderPartial`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Спасибо. Я сперва его неправильно использовал и подумал, что это не то.- Перечитал- должно быть такого вида @Html.Partial("~/Views/MyView.cshtml")   -Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/MyView.cshtml")
```

Спасибо @Igor